# Applying the norm and metric on a space of continuous functions

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

I have defined the space of continuous functions (complex trigonometric functions) by the given definitions:

*Definition*

A normed vector space, $X$, is said to be complete (Banach) iff and only if every sequence is convergent in norm (Cauchy).

*Definition*

Let $a < b$  be real numbers. Let then $C[a,b]$ denote  the set of real-valued continuous
functions with domain $[a, b]$.

*Definition*

Let $f$ be any real-valued function on some domain $\mathscr{D}$, with variable $t$. We can then define the norm  of $f$ by
$$||f||_\infty = \underset{t\in \mathscr{D}}{\text{sup}} |f(t)|$$

*Definition*

The metric, defining the distance between two elements $f_1,f_2\in X$, where $X$ is a Banach space (see def. 3, 4), is then measured by
$$d(f_1,f_2)=\underset{t \in \mathscr{D}}{max}\big|f_1(t)-f_2(t)\big|$$

However, one thing does not add up.

When I want to apply the metric on two elements, say $f_1= e^{it}-\cos2t$ and $f_2=e^{2it^2}$, it will only work if I integrate the elements over the interval $[a,b]$ and apply the modulus on the result to get a real value.

Does it mean that I have to use the metric

$$ \forall \ \ f_1,f_2 \in C:d_2(f_1,f_2):=\bigg|\bigg(\int_a^b\big(f_1(t)-f_2(t)\big)^2 dt\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg|$$

and therefore go over the $L^2$ space instead? If yes, then it cannot be Hilbert space, because the elements $f_k$ are nonlinear continuous trigonometric functions on $\mathbb{C}^2$, and are not orthogonal to one another. So this would be $L^2$ "without" an inner product. What would the right name of the vector space be in this case?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused, why can't you use $\| f - g\|_{\infty}$ as your metric? This is perfectly valid metric (any norm induces metric)

Comment: Please define $||f-g||_\infty$

Comment: You defined norm $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$ yourself, I just apply it to difference $f - g$ which exists in vector space

Comment: I didn't explicitely, do you mean $||f-g||_\infty=\int_a^b |f_1(t)-f_2(t)| dt$?

Comment: You wrote down $\|f \|_{\infty} = \sup_{t \in \mathcal D} |f(t)|$, here $\mathcal D = [a, b]$. Now I see you defined it only for real valued functions $f$, but nothing stops it from being defined for complex valued ones.

Comment: If you mean that $||f-g||=|f|-|g|$ without any integration, then that does not work, I get complex values which have no meaning as a measure of difference between two elements.

Comment: The standard way to define $f - g$ in vector space is $(f - g)(t) = f(t) - g(t)$. I don't get either how you get complex values from $|f| - |g|$, which would be difference of positive numbers at any point.

Comment: $|f - g|$ is a real-valued function for any complex-valued functions $f$ and $g$, and thus has a well-defined supremum. Could you show the work you did to get those complex values? It would help in seeing where things went wrong.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I will copy and paste the work tomorrow. Hope to see you then!

Comment: @eyeballfrog This metric is ok as you said, but it is not OK for the interval $[a,b]$, it is only good for a single point $|f(a)-g(a)|$. So in order to use it, I just integrate it over  $[a,b]$, hence $\int_a^b |(f(t)-g(t)|dt$

Comment: You're forgetting the $\max$ part. The distance between the functions under this metric is the largest value of $|f(x) - g(x)|$ among all $x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog you are right, but what is then $\int_a^b |f(t)-g(t)|dt$, is it just an integral, and has nothing to do with the metric?

Comment: It's a *different* metric. That metric is the $L_1$ metric, while the metric in the problem is the $L_\infty$ metric. Both are quite important to mathematics, though this problem deals only with the latter.

Comment: I will have to use that $L_1$ metric then, because it gives real values which describe the area between the graphs of f an g. Thanks

Comment: @eyeballfrog Have a look at https://rorasa.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/l0-norm-l1-norm-l2-norm-l-infinity-norm/ here l_1 norm is a different thing again.

Comment: @eyeballfrog is there confusion on notation between $L1$ and $l_1$ here? The integration I am doing works ONLY if I use the series of the functions over a given interval. Here L1, the space of Lebesgue integrable functions while 
ℓ1, the space of absolutely convergent sequences. Which of these is the norm you refer to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142601/discussion-between-eyeballfrog-and-luthier415hz).

Comment: @eyeballfrog Can you look at this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4636408/a-question-regarding-the-fourier-series-sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misquoted the definitions.

Let's start with

> *Definition*
>
> A normed vector space, $X$, is said to be complete (Banach) iff and
> only if every sequence is convergent in norm (Cauchy).

No. A Banach space is a complete normed vector space. But "complete" means that every *Cauchy sequence* converges. Where a *Cauchy sequence* is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ that satisfies the *Cauchy condition*
$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N, \forall n,m > N, \|x_n - x_m\| < \epsilon$$

"Cauchy" has to modify "sequence" here (not anything else) to make any sense. You cannot just throw it in at the end as an afterthought.

There is also a problem with this definition:

> *Definition*
>
> Let $f$ be any real-valued function on some domain $\mathscr{D}$, with
> variable $t$. We can then define the norm  of $f$ by $$\|f\|_\infty =
> \underset{t\in \mathscr{D}}{\text{sup}} |f(t)|$$

That only defines a norm when $f$ is a *bounded* function. For instance $\mathscr D = (0,\infty)$ is a domain, and $f(x) = \frac 1x$ is a function on it. But $ \underset{t\in \mathscr{D}}{\text{sup}} |f(t)| = \infty$, which is not an allowed value for a norm.

While "bounded" is a necessary condition on $f$, "real-valued" is not. Notice in the definition you are not taking the supremum over values $f(t)$, but rather over values $|f(t)|$. When $f$ is complex-valued, $|f(t)|$ is still only real-valued, so the definition still works.

Now all functions in $C[a,b]$ are bounded, so this shouldn't affect the rest of your post

> *Definition*
>
> The metric, defining the distance between two elements $f_1,f_2\in X$,
> where $X$ is a Banach space (see def. 3, 4), is then measured by
> $$d(f_1,f_2)=\underset{t \in\mathscr{D}}{max}\big|f_1(t)-f_2(t)\big|$$

This is okay, but I just want to point out that "Banach" is unnecessary. This is how distance is defined in any space with the supremum (aka uniform) norm. More generally, in any space with a norm $\|\cdot\|, d(f_1, f_2) = \|f_1 - f_2\|$.

> When I want to apply the metric on two elements, say $f_1=
>  e^{it}-\cos2t$ and $f_2=e^{2it^2}$, it will only work if I integrate
> the elements over the interval $[a,b]$ and apply the modulus on the
> result to get a real value.

This is false. $\|f\|_\infty$ is a valid norm and works just fine for those two functions. You haven't specified what interval $[a,b]$ you are using in this example, but I'll use the obvious $[0,2\pi]$. But it is still valid no matter what interval is used.

$$\begin{align}d(f_1,f_2) &= \|f_1 - f_2\|_\infty\\&=\sup_{0 \le t \le 2\pi} |f_1(t) - f_2(t)|\\&=\sup_{0 \le t \le 2\pi} |e^{it} - \cos 2t - e^{2it^2}|\\&=\sup \{ |e^{it} - \cos 2t - e^{2it^2}| : 0 \le t\le 2\pi\}\end{align}$$

Note that $|e^{it} - \cos 2t - e^{2it^2}|\le |e^{it}| + |\cos 2t| + |e^{2it^2}| \le 1 + 1 + 1 = 3$ for all $t$.

Thus every element of the set $\{ |e^{it} - \cos 2t - e^{2it^2}| : 0 \le t\le 2\pi\}$ is $\le 3$ in value. Any set of real numbers that is bounded above has a supremum. The value of that supremum may not always be easy to calculate, but it still exists.

Comment: Thanks for this Paul. The problem I am trying to solve by these definitions is to define the right linear metric space-type for defining "Converging sequences on a closed interval on the real line".  That is, $l_1$, according to the discussion with @Eyeballfrog, out of which I need to define the norm and metric.

Comment: There are many different spaces that meet that description, but eyeballfrog knows this, so I'll assume they are sorting out exactly what you need.