# What type of linear metric space represents this sequence?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, fourier-series

I have a piece-wise function in $\mathbb{R}^2$,, which is bounded on $[a,b]$ . This function is bounded on  [-5,5] and looks like

[image]

the function looks like this:

[image]

(the left vertical line is a actually a "curly bracket") defining the set of intervals that build up the piecewise function (which is shown here only in part for graphical limitations).

When I convert this to a Fourier series in [Mathematica](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html), I use the sum:

$$ y_k=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k \cos nt +\beta_k\sin nt$$

where the components:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cc}
     \alpha_0=\frac{1}{2(b-a)}\int_{a}^b f(t)\text{d}t \\
     \alpha_k=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^b f(t)\cos kt \text{d}t \\
     \beta_k=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^b f(t)\sin kt \text{d}t
\end{array}
\end{equation}

are solved where $f(t)$  is given in the piecewise function given above.

This gives a nice analytic function, bounded on [-5,5]:

[image]

This new function looks like this:

$$0.591549 + (0.0345161 + 0.0266358 I) e^{-I t} + (0.0345161 - 
    0.0266358 I) e^{-I t} + (0.236242 + 0.227141 I) e^{2I t}+ (0.236242 -    0.227141 I) e^{2I t} + (0.217808 - 0.202757 I) e^{-3I t} + (0.217808 +    0.202757 I) e^{3I t} + (1.09053 - 0.00582322 I) e^{-4I t} + (1.09053 +     0.00582322 I) e^{4I t}+ (1.68527 - 0.355833 I) e^{-5I t} + (1.68527 +     0.355833 I) e^{5I t} + (0.362947 - 0.998453 I) e^{-6I t} + (0.362947 +    0.998453 I) e^{6I t} + (1.01148 - 0.0130695 I) e^{-7I t} + (1.01148 +     0.0130695 I) e^{7I t} - (0.398096 + 0.214324 I) e^{-8I t} - (0.398096 -     0.214324 I) e^{-8I t} + (0.138399 - 0.464199 I) e^{-9I t} + (0.138399 +     0.464199 I) e^{9I t} + (0.0348431 - 0.684121 I) e^{-10I t} + (0.0348431 +     0.684121 I) e^{10I t}$$

I want to define what this Fourier series projection actually is.

I assume this is a projection given by:

$$y_k: \mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow C^\infty[a,b]$$

since we obtain a continuous infinitely differentiable function from a piecewise  function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the Fourier series projection.

So would this assumption be correct, that we go from $R^2$ to a space of bounded sequence $C^\infty[a,b]$?

However, this function "repeats" itself outside the boundaries of the original piecewise-functions $f(t)$ , which are [-5,5].
So something tells me we are actually looking at an unbounded sequence, and it does not even converge on $[-\infty,\infty]$ since the plot is showing an infinitely repeated sequence of the Fourier series:

Function on the interval [-10, 10]:

[image]

Function on the interval [-50, 50]:

[image]

About the scope:
I am looking for the right norm and metric, in order to do an analysis of this function on $[a,b]$.

But not being sure, I ask here:

What is the correct definition of the space of this repeating sequence, is it $C^\infty[a,b]$ or $\ell^\infty$? Or is it instead an $L^1$ space?

Clearly the function on $[a,b]$ forms a subspace which can be replicated infinitely many times. So I am thinking also about Hilbert space, but this is repeated infinitely many times on the same dimension, so we do not have infinitely many dimensions.

What I can tell from the plots, is that the norm of the function is finite. However, the function is unbounded if I increase the interval of plotting, so it appears to me to be an unbounded sequence, which is infinitely differentiable. But at the same time, this unboundedness is merely n-repetitions of that Fourier series.

So what is the correct answer here, and why?

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean by "when I convert this to a Fourier series" in the beginning of the question.

Comment: I take the Fourier series of the first interval of the step wise function, $f(t)$, and sum it to the Fourier series of the next interval, and so on.

Comment: I still don't follow. This is really THE key step and you should expand your question to explain it carefully, imho

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4635821

Comment: @student91 this is not related. This you refer to is the Fourier TRANSFORM. Here we discuss the series.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro see update

Comment: Fourier series expand PERIODIC functions. In your case the function can be extended as a periodic function with period 10 and this periodic function can be expanded in Fourier series. However, the period plays a role in the formulas, see for example https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html

Comment: This is a good point, the period is $2\pi$. But a sine function is periodic too, and that is element in $C^\infty$ space. So this is a $C^\infty$ space, as suggested!

Comment: An infinite sum of $C^\infty$ functions is not necessarily $C^\infty$. For example any periodic $L^2$ function  has a Fourier series with coefficients in $\ell^2$.

Comment: Thanks. That makes things really harder! Do you have an idea of what the answer of this question is?

Comment: @Gribouillis I think you answered it! It is $L^2$

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by «the Fourier series mapping». The question is unclear as it is.

Comment: Projection, is a better word than mapping.